# apt-get update not working in parrot OS

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, debian, parrot-os

i am trying to to do a `sudo apt-get update` in parrot OS, but all i get is this error

```
Err:1 http://your.repo.domain/repository JollyRoger InRelease
  Could not resolve 'your.repo.domain'
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                   
Hit:4 http://deb.playonlinux.com wheezy InRelease                                            
Get:5 http://mirrordirector.archive.parrotsec.org/parrot parrot InRelease [14.6 kB]          
Err:5 http://mirrordirector.archive.parrotsec.org/parrot parrot InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ED05F7B2EC3C9224
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://mirrordirector.archive.parrotsec.org/parrot parrot InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ED05F7B2EC3C9224
E: The repository 'http://mirrordirector.archive.parrotsec.org/parrot parrot InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

how can i fix it permanently?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

The apt packaging system has a set of trusted keys that determine whether a package can be authenticated and therefore trusted to be installed on the system. Sometimes the system does not have all the keys it needs and runs into this issue. Fortunately, there is a quick fix. Each key that is listed as missing needs to be added to the apt key manager so that it can authenticate the packages.

Looking at the error above, apt is telling us that the following key is missing:

```
NO_PUBKEY ED05F7B2EC3C9224
```

To add these keys, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ED05F7B2EC3C9224
```

Something very similar should be executed

> Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.QTeppiINUh --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
>   gpg: requesting key 437D05B5 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
>   gpg: key 437D05B5: public key "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key " imported
>   gpg: Total number processed: 1
>   gpg:               imported: 1

And Voila!!! You should be able to run your update command

Comment: Thanks [moathaytham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9409560/moathaytham), it's working just fine now. I really appreciate it.

Comment: It's my pleasure @sadatt_254

Answer (score 1):

Edit /etc/resolv.conf. In a Terminal window run

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment out all other 'nameservers' #

and add the line

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

and save. Press ctr + x then press the letter 'y' and press Enter again,

Then do

`ping www.google.com`

If this succeeds then run the following commands

```
sudo apt-get --download-only --reinstall install resolvconf
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends resolvconf
sudo apt-get install resolvconf
```

Good luck! it worked for me.

P.S. Dont do while logged as root